# Angular File Upload custom mat error issue

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular5, angular6

I have a form for uploading a file in an angular 5 app.For which i want to display custom error if the format of the file does not match with the following :

**And the user should see the error message, "Only PDF, Excel, Powerpoint, or Audio (wav and wmv) files are accepted."**

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<div class="detail-item">
                                        <span class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                                            <input #file type="file" class="inputfile" name="input-file-preview" (change)="OnchangeFile($event)" />
                                            <span class="fs-btn fs-btn-standard file-selection" (click)="file.click()">{{'DTM.BulletinPublication.browse' | translate}}</span>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="file-name">
                                            <mat-form-field>
                                                <input id="fileName" matInput placeholder="File Name" formControlName="fileName" readonly="readonly">
                                                <mat-error>{{getErrorMessageForFileFormat()}}</mat-error>
                                            </mat-form-field>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
```

Here is the "onFileChange" method used in the fileUpload control:

```
 OnchangeFile(evt: any): void {
        let files: File[] = evt.target.files;
        let file: File = files[0];
        if (files && file) {
            let isValidFileFormat = this.checkForFileExtention(file);

            this.filename = file.name;
            let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            this.publishBulletinForm.get(BulletinFields.fileName).setValue(file.name);
            this.publishBulletinForm.get(BulletinFields.fileName).updateValueAndValidity();
            if (this.isEdit) {
                this.bulletinFileNameChange();
            }


            if (!isValidFileFormat)
            {
               *this.publishBulletinForm.get(BulletinFields.fileName).setErrors({ 'incorrect': true });*

            }
        }
    }
```

and here is the code for the custom validator I have written and used:-

```
getErrorMessageForFileFormat(): string {
        let me: BulletinsPublishComponent = this;
        let errMsg: string = '';
        if (me.publishBulletinForm.get(BulletinFields.fileName).hasError('required')) {
            errMsg = me.getTranslation('DTM.BulletinPublication.FileTypeRequired');
            this.isFormValid = false;
        }
        else if (me.publishBulletinForm.get(BulletinFields.fileName).hasError('incorrect')) {
            errMsg = me.getTranslation('DTM.BulletinPublication.InvalidFileType');
            this.isFormValid = false;
        }

        me.cd.markForCheck();
        return errMsg;
    }
```

No matter what i do it never display the error message.Can some one please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for what strange reason `markForCheck()` did not work, but the following changes helped me out to show custom error while uploading invalid file format.

```
if (!isValidFileFormat)
{
    this.publishBulletinForm.get(BulletinFields.fileName).markAsTouched();
    this.publishBulletinForm.get(BulletinFields.fileName).setErrors({ 'incorrect': true });  
}
```